# Como deletar um JSON dentro de um Array no localStorage()

Tags: javascript, json, aplicação-web, app, localstorage

Estou criando um App de **anotações** e gostaria de poder excluir a respectiva nota, quando o usuário clicar, criei essa função porem não esta retornando nada para meu **localStorage()**, gostaria de saber se há alguma outra alternativa para eu deletar o **JSON dentro do Array de notas**.

**Meu código:**

```
function deleteNote(noteId) {             
    let jsonData = localStorage.getItem("notes")

    let data = JSON.parse(jsonData)                
        
    for (item in data) {          
        for (i=0; i < data[item].length; i++) {
            if(data[item][i].id == noteId){
                data[item].splice(i, 1)
                break;
             }
         }
     }        
     localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(data))                        
}
```

**Itens dentro do localStorage():**
[image: Meu localStorage]

Comment: O que o código que você anexou na pergunta está fazendo? Era para remover uma nota? Se sim, não estaria faltando um parâmetro `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devias passar um argumento como por exemplo id ou noteId para saber qual é o id a ser removido

```
function deleteNote(id) {             
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')).filter(item => item.noteId !== id)
  localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que eu precisava :)